# using Bit (bitsrc.io) and putting the right files in .gitignore

Tags: bit-src

What files generated by Bit are clear to be included in .gitignore? What are the best practices regarding using Bit and Git combined?

Answer (score 1):

Bitsrc create 3 main assets:

1. `bit.json` - should be committed to source control.
2. `.bitmap` - should be committed to source control.
3. `.bit` if git isn't used or `.git/bit` folder if git is used. This shouldn't be committed to git and should be synced with `bit import` command right after a clone.

Comment: more info on `bit init`, its side-effects and what needs to be committed to Git (and why) - https://docs.bitsrc.io/docs/initializing-bit.html